# Replace subimage by its average value

Tags: c++, algorithm, image, opencv

I have the input image `in`, and the mask image `lev` (which label each pixel as a number from 1 to `nlevels`, `nlevels`=4). I need to get image out, which from each region `in==lev` will be replaced by its average value.

Here is my brute force approach.  I'm wondering if there is any better way of doing it.

```
Mat ACA::global_average(Mat in, const Mat &lev)
{
    // in: CV_32F
    // lev: CV_32S
    int M=in.rows;
    int N=in.cols;

    in.convertTo(in, CV_32FC3);

    // vector holds average value for each category
    vector<float> count(nlevels,0);
    vector<Vec3f> average(nlevels);

    int pixlev;
    for (int i=0; i < M; i++)
        for (int j=0; j < N; j++)
        {
            pixlev = lev.at<int>(i,j);
            assert (pixlev<nlevels);

            average[pixlev] += in.at<Vec3f>(i,j);
            count[pixlev]++;
        }

    for (int i=0; i<nlevels; i++)
        average[i] /=count[i];


    Mat out=Mat::zeros(M,N,CV_32FC3);
    for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            pixlev = lev.at<int>(i,j);
            out.at<Vec3f>(i,j)=average[pixlev];
        }
    return out;
}
```

P/S:

Here is an example.

Input Image:

[image: Original Image]
Mask image, it is basically a matrix labelling the pixels into one of 4 categories

[image: Mask Image]

Output picture is the average of input image, for each category of pixels. For example, at first I find all pixels has category 1, find their average, and replace all those pixels by the average value.

[image: Output picture]

Comment: I don't really follow your description, especially what average you are taking. Could you provide a simple input / lev / output example? Also if you could comment your code I guess it will help people help you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's clear to me now. I'll check it out when I have time.

Comment: Apart from few missing {} on the outer for loops, it looks good to me

Comment: I also don't see any particular inefficiencies in it. Did you have some ideas that you weren't able to implement?

Comment: I'm thinking of using convolution to perform averaging ( and convolution can be calculated through FFT(n logn). But nevermind, this should be good enough as you guys point out.

Answer (score 6):

## Algorithm

You will benefit greatly from using OpenCV's built-in functionality rather than performing this operation yourself. OpenCV supports masked operations, which will only apply to pixels where the mask is nonzero.

```
cv::Mat global_average(const cv::Mat& input, const cv::Mat& levels)
{
    assert(levels.channels() == 1);
    cv::Mat output(input.size(), input.type());
    for (int level = 0; level < nlevels; ++level)
    {
        const cv::Mat mask = levels == level;
        const cv::Scalar avg = cv::mean(input, mask);
        output.setTo(avg, mask);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Using functionality already present in OpenCV is not only clearer and shorter (by a factor of 3), but also allows the code to be more flexible. You will notice:

- There is no explicit type conversion or array indexing occurring, which is safer.
- This code is also more flexible: you do not need to convert your images to floating-point or integers.
- It can operate on 8-bit images as well, which can give a significant speedup, since most of the time in the algorithm will be spent on memory access. Simply using the raw 8-bit images gives a ~15% speedup in my tests.
- It is also possible that OpenCV functions may benefit from hardware and parallelism optimizations, which could make them faster than raw loops.

## Code Style

#### Whitespace

Put spaces around your assignments and comparisons: `int i=0; i<m;` is harder to read than `int i = 0; i < M;`. Also, be consistent. Sometimes you do this already, but most of the time you do not.

#### Braces

You have nested `for` loops, but only the inner loop has braces. Both loops should have braces surrounding the body for consistency.

#### Precondition Checking

Although it is good that you leave comments indicating the data types you expect from `in` and `lev`, it is better to verify this in code. Adding assertions about these conditions makes it easier to debug if a wrong parameter is passed:

```
assert(in.depth() == CV_32F);
assert(lev.depth() == CV_32S);
```

#### Use `const` when you can

Both `M` and `N` do not change during the function evaluation. They can be declared as `const int` to allow the compiler to perform checks that they are never accidentally modified. Additionally, you can reduce the scope of `pixlev` by declaring it inside each of the loops. Then it too can be made `const`:

```
const int pixlev = lev.at<int>(i,j); // or use auto to reduce type duplication
```